# Using Async method for long runnning process does not allow other process start (ASP.net MVC)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I have written a web application (ASP.net MVC). When I click a button, the following function is called:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> ProcessDrift()
{
    Task task = await Task.WhenAny(ProcessAsyncDrift());
    return Json(new { result = "ok"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public async Task ProcessAsyncDrift()
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        LongRunningProcess();
    });
}
```

I tested it on local server, it works well, but when I test it on server ( windows 2012 R2), after clicking the button, I can not open any other page of site (in the same browser) until the process is finished.

What should I do?

Comment: Other requests to your site shouldnt be blocked,  unless your long running process gobbles up lots of threads,are you getting 503s?